# ¿En Java los argumentos se pasan por valor o por referencia?

Tags: java, paso-por-valor, paso-por-referencia

Siempre pensé que en Java los parámetros se pasan **por referencia** en el caso de los objetos y **por valor** en el caso de los tipos primitivos. Pero hay sitios en que se dice que todos los parámetros se pasan por valor, por ejemplo, [aquí (en inglés)](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm), que indican que esto no es cierto. Creo que no entiendo la diferencia que están haciendo. ¿Cuál es la explicación?

*Esta pregunta es una copia traducida y modificada del original [Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) que es una comunity wiki originalmente redactada por [user4315](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4315/user4315) y no necesariamente representa la opinión de user4315 al respecto.*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Aclaración con otros lenguajes

Gran parte de la confusión de este problema es que se usan diferentes definiciones para el termino "referencia". La gente que viene de C++ pueden asumir que "referencia" significa lo mismo que en C++, los que vienen de C pueden pensar que "referencia" es lo mismo que "puntero" en C.

Paso por referencia (Pass by reference) en Java depende del significado del termino "referencia".

---

### Java paso por valor (Pass by value)

En Java los argumentos se pasan **siempre** por valor. Desafortunadamente, cuando pasamos un objeto estamos pasando una referencia a el. Esto puede ser confuso para los principiantes.

Esto es lo que sucede:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Perro unPerro = new Perro("Lupo");
        cambiarNombre(unPerro);
        //Print Lupo
        System.out.println( "Ahora el perro se llama : " + 
                            unPerro.obtenerNombre() );
    }

    public static void cambiarNombre(Perro p) {
        p = new Perro("Fifi");
    }
}
```

En este ejemplo, `unPerro.obtenerNombre()` todavía devuelve `"Lupo"`. El valor de la variable `unPerro` no es sobreescrito en el método `cambiarNombre` con el `Perro` llamado `"Fifi"` dado que la referencia al objeto se pasa por valor. Esto significa que en el método `cambiarNombre` se pasa **una copia** del valor de la referencia del objeto `Perro` que se encuentra en el método cliente (para este caso, `main`). Si se pasase por referencia, entonces `unPerro.obtenerNombre()` en `main` devolvería `"Fifi"` tras llamar a `cambiarNombre` puesto que se ha actualizado la referencia almacenada en el objeto `Perro` declarado en el método cliente.

Para que sí se cambiase el nombre, el método `cambiarNombre` debería alterar el estado del valor del objeto enviado como parámetro. Esto se logra así:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Perro unPerro = new Perro("Lupo");
        cambiarNombre(unPerro);
        //Print Fifi
        System.out.println( "Ahora el perro se llama : " + 
                            unPerro.obtenerNombre() );
    }

    public static void cambiarNombre(Perro p) {
        p.asignaNombre("Fifi");
    }
}
```

Es decir, desde el método `cambiarNombre` podemos cambiar el contenido del `Perro` que se le pasa y esos cambios después se verán reflejados en el `Perro` referenciado por `unPerro`. Pero desde `cambiarNombre` no podemos hacer que la variable `unPerro` referencie a otro `Perro`.

La implementación de `Perro` es :

```
public class Perro {
    private String miNombre;
    public Perro(String nombre) {
        miNombre = nombre;
    }
    public String obtenerNombre() {
        return miNombre;
    }
    public void asignaNombre(String nombre) {
        miNombre = nombre;
    }
}
```

Una fuente de confusión muy habitual es pensar que las referencias en Java y en C++ son parecidas por tener el mismo nombre. Esto es indiscutíblemente falso. Tienes una descripción detallada de esto en esta [pregunta y respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1483/qu%C3%A9-diferencias-hay-entre-las-referencias-y-punteros-en-c-y-en-java/1484#1484).

*Esta respuesta es una copia traducida y modificada de [una respuesta original en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/956880) que es una comunity wiki originalmente redactada por [erlando](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4192/erlando). Y no refleja necesariamente la opinión de erlando.*

Comment: ¿Alguno de los que han hecho -1 podría explicar qué está mal en la respuesta? @JordiCastilla Con respecto a la wiki, no; no tiene por que ser wiki y no va  a ser wiki; véase esto http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/294/301

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Las referencias en Java no son "punteros sin aritmetica de punteros", como tú comentas. Eso todavía confundirá más a los "novatos". Por eso mi voto negativo. Si lo corriges, votaré positivo, porque todo lo demás está bien.

Comment: Pienso que si vas a hablar de aritmética de punteros entonces deberías ahondar un poco en ese tema para evitar confusiones a los lectores, sobretodo a los novatos.

Comment: @ArturoTena y Luiggi Mendoza , tenéis razón. Siendo estrictos las referencias en Java son distintas de los punteros en C++. A mi me resultan más similares las referencias en Java a los punteros en C++ que a las referencias en C++. Pero esto es opinable y lo he eliminado de la respuesta. He puesto una explicación detallada sobre el tema que espero aclare dudas al respecto.

Comment: Yo quitaría todo el parrafo que compara c++ y java. La pregunta queda respondida perfectamente con el ejemplo del perro y el resto confunde. Habrá gente que ni sepa o le intetese c++. Parece que la pregunta en inglès tambièn lo deja ahí.

Comment: @MiguelGarcia , pues sí, se ha quedado demasiado larga y es algo que no concierne diréctamente a la pregunta. Así que lo he separado en una pregunta y respuesta aparte.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Buena idea. Oye, ya acéptate tu propia respuesta aquí. 

Comment: **si es una wiki, hazla wiki** ᕦ ´• ᴥ •` ᕥ

Answer (score 1):

En *Java* los parámetros, se pasan por valor, aunque hay casos en los cuales el código se ejecuta de manera similar a que si fuera paso por referencia , pero esto no es así.

Cuando tú envías un parámetro *Java* crea una copia de la variable y se la envía al método. Si utilizas datos primitivos no le debes dar mayor importancia, simplemente el contenido de la variable será igual al valor antes de ser enviado al método.

Si los parámetros que envías, son objetos debes fijarte en que estos, sean mutables o inmutables. De ser mutables debes tener mucho cuidado, ya que se crea una copia de esa referencia apuntando al mismo objeto. Por lo tanto el cambio que realices dentro de un método afectará a la variable original.

Dejo un ejemplo para que lo valides por ti mismo:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int variableA = 5;
    int variableB = 10;

    System.out.println("variable A antes del intercambio : " +variableA);
    System.out.println("variable B antes del intercambio : " +variableB);

    intercambio(variableA, variableB);

    System.out.println("variable A despues del intercambio : " +variableA);
    System.out.println("variable B despues del intercambio : " +variableB);


    StringBuilder cadenaA = new StringBuilder("cadenaA");
    StringBuilder cadenaB = new StringBuilder("cadenaB");

    System.out.println("cadena A antes del intercambio : " +cadenaA);
    System.out.println("cadena B antes del intercambio : " +cadenaB);

    intercambio(cadenaA, cadenaB);

    System.out.println("cadena A despues del intercambio : " +cadenaA);
    System.out.println("cadena B despues del intercambio : " +cadenaB);


}

public static void intercambio(int variableA,int variableB)
{
    System.out.println("variable A dentro del metodo : " +variableA);
    System.out.println("variable B dentro del metodo : " +variableB);

    int auxiliar = variableA;
    variableA = variableB;
    variableB = auxiliar;

    System.out.println("variable A dentro del metodo : " +variableA);
    System.out.println("variable B dentro del metodo : " +variableB);
}

public static void intercambio(StringBuilder cadenaA,StringBuilder cadenaB)
{
    System.out.println("cadena A dentro del metodo : " + cadenaA);
    System.out.println("cadena B dentro del metodo : " + cadenaB);

    cadenaA.append("texto");
    cadenaB.append("texto");

    System.out.println("cadena A dentro del metodo : " + cadenaA);
    System.out.println("cadena B dentro del metodo : " + cadenaB);

}
```

Comment: Esta parte me parece muy importante ponerle atencion: "[Al utilizar objetos mutables] se crea una copia de esa referencia **apuntando al mismo objeto**."