# ¿Qué diferencias hay entre las referencias y punteros en C++ y en Java?

Tags: java, c++, punteros

Tanto Java como C++ tienen referencias.

¿Son prácticamente lo mismo o son significativamente diferentes?
Java no tiene punteros. ¿Son entonces las referencias en Java como los punteros de C++?
¿Hay estructuras de código en lo que a referencias y punteros se refiere que sean iguales en los dos lenguajes pero hagan cosas distintas?

Comment: Esto me suena a Gorilla vs Shark: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/

Comment: Yo no estoy preguntando qué es mejor si las referencias en Java o en C++ o los punteros en C++. Esa pregunta que no estoy haciendo sería como la de los tiburones y los gorilas. Yo pregunto por las diferencias entre ellas, sin entrar en cuales son preferibles, que es algo muy relevante para un porcentaje enorme de programadores que usan C++ y Java y que pueden sufrir de errores de programación si no las tienen claras.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos como reflexión y analizando el articulo. Creo no solo se considera preguntar las diferencias... *Es verdad que se pueden comparar las diferencias entre los punteros de [tag:c++] y [tag:java]*. Pero **¿un experto gastará su día en ello?** o **¿es una pregunta realmente útil en el aprendizaje de alguien?**. Eso no quita que me parezca muy interesante como articulo o blog, pero quizás no realmente para es.SO.

Comment: @JordiCastilla a todo aquel que sabe Java y está aprendiendo C++ le interesa saber que a=b en C++ con referencias hace algo totalmente distinto a lo que está acostumbrado en Java.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos lo siento pero discrepo totalmente. Aprender cualquier lenguaje de programación, plug-in o framework con ideas preconcebidas de lo anterior que sabes lo único que hace es dificultarte el aprendizaje y el entendimiento de la materia, provocando malas costumbres. Es complicado borrar la mente y empezar de cero cuando piensas que ya sabes programar, pero es lo mas efectivo. *Tenia un profe que lo comparaba con el conductor de coche que por haber conducido moto, saca la cabeza por la ventanilla para mirar atrás en vez de usar el retrovisor.* :) :)

Comment: @JordiCastilla totalmente de acuerdo. Yo soy de los que aprendí Java partiendo de la suposición de que se parecía a C++, lo cual no me ayudó sino todo lo contrario. Y creo que esta pregunta ayuda a quienes cometieron el  mismo error que yo a no cometerlo.

Comment: No lo veo asi. Como he dicho antes: para programadores ya expertos en las dos disciplinas, **es un articulo de revista o blog especializado muy válido y la verdad, muy interesante**. Pero hay que ver el contexto, y estamos en **es.SO**, un espacio el que la gente busca respuestas a problemas concretos y para este sitio, lo veo inadecuado.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos desde el momento que **C++ permite acceder a los punteros de las variables y Java no** ya existe una diferencia notable entre ambos lenguajes. Tu pregunta tiene un transfondo que me suena más a *¿qué diferencia existe entre punteros y referencias?* y está brevemente explicado aquí: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referencia_(informática)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para un programador de C++ senior, la mejor forma de explicarle java, o parte del java, es decirle:

- Todas las declaraciones de variables, parametros, atributos, etc que sean de tipo Object o que hereden de Object son siempre "punteros".
- Los objetos nunca residen en el "stack" o en "memoria global" residen siempre en el "heap" de objetos java.
- La razon de que no exista en java el puntero de C++ (el "*") en dichas declaraciones, es que esta siempre 100% implicito y es imposible declarar variables de objetos que no sean punteros (al estilo de C++ sin "*"). Osease de objetos que no residan en el "heap".
- Como todas las declaraciones (varibles etc) que heredan de Object siempre son punteros, y no hay posibilidad de otra cosa, eliminaron el "*", siempre va implicito.
- Siempre se usa "new" para crear nuevas instancias. No se pueden crear nuevas instancias de objetos sin "new". (o uso de JNI).
- No se puede hacer "delete" de los objetos, es la JVM la que sabe que objetos son "vivos" y cuales no. El garbage collector mira la "sopa" de objetos existente y a partir de unas "roots" sabe decidir cual esta vivo (es accesible) y cual ya no es accesible desde las "roots".
- Los objetos java pueden cambiar de direccion de memoria en el tiempo. Pero el programador nunca ve cuales son esas direcciones (a diferencia de C++), y la JVM siempre mantiene la integridad de la "sopa" de objetos java en el "heap", cuando mueve un objeto de direccion, todas las referencias de los clientes cambian adecuadamente. Esto es 100% transparente al programador / usuario.
- A cualquier variable, de tipo Object o que hereda de Object, se le puede asignar siempre un null (TODAS esas declaraciones son punteros).

Answer (score 3):

Una fuente de confusión muy habitual es pensar que las referencias en Java y en C++ son parecidas por tener el mismo nombre. Esto es indiscutíblemente falso.

Considera una clase en C++ o Java llamada Perro con un constructor que admite un nombre y métodos obtenerNombre y asignaNombre.

En Java este código que usa referencias es válido :

```
Perro perroA = new Perro("Gordito");
// Puedes cambiar la referencia contenida en perroA
perroA = new Perro("Gruñon");
Perro perroB;  //  Puedes declarar una variable de tipo referencia
                // sin inicializarla explícitamente.
perroB = new Perro("Comilon"); // Y luego asignarle un objeto 
perroB = perroA; // Ahora perroA y perroB referencian el mismo objeto
perroA.asignaNombre("Fifi"); // Modifica tanto perroA como perroB
System.out.println(perroB.obtenerNombre()); // Imprimie "Fifi"
```

El mismo código en C++ usando referencias no compila y cuando compila (quitando las líneas marcadas con `!!!`) hace cosas distintas al de Java :

```
Perro perroObj1("Gordito");
Perro perroObj2("Comilon");

Perro& perroA = perroObj1; // Correcto
//  No puedes cambiar el objeto al que referencia 
// una variable tipo referencia en C++
perroA = Perro("Gruñon"); // Compila, pero no hace lo mismo que en Java
// perroA sique referenciando al mismo objeto, no a otro como en Java
// Lo que sucede en C++ es que se invoca el operador de asignación.
Perro& perroB; //  !!!Error compilacion. No puedes declarar variables 
               // referencia sin inicializarlas.
perroB = perroObj2; // !!! Demasiado tarde
Perro& perroB = perroObj2; // Correcto
perroB = perroA; // No hace lo mismo que en java
perroA.asignaNombre("Fifi"); // Modificamos perroA pero no perroB
std::cout << perroB.obtenerNombre() << std::endl; // Imprimie "Gruñon", no "Fifi"
```

El mismo código en C++ con punteros sí sería valido y hace lo mismo que en java.

```
Perro* perroA = new Perro("Gordito");
// Puedes cambiar el puntero contenido en perroA
perroA = new Perro("Gruñon"); 
Perro* perroB;  //  Puedes declarar una variable de tipo puntero 
                // sin inicializarla explícitamente.
perroB = new Perro("Comilon"); // Y luego asignarle un puntero a objeto  
perroB = perroA; // Ahora perroA y perroB apuntan al mismo objeto    
perroA->asignaNombre( "Fifi" ); // Modifica tanto perroA como perroB
std::cout << perroB->obtenerNombre() << std::endl; // Imprime "Fifi"
```

También son muy diferentes las referencias de Java a las de C++ en lo que a paso de parámetros se refiere.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Perro unPerro = new Perro("Tim");
    cambiarNombre( unPerro );
}
public static void cambiarNombre(Perro p) {
    p = new Perro("Fifi"); // No modifica unPerro en main
}
```

En las referencias de C++ tampoco se hace que unPerro referencie a otro objeto pero, a diferencia de lo que ocurre en Java, sí que cambia el contenido de `unPerro` en `main` como consecuencia de como funciona el operador asignación (suponiendo una implementación normal del operador asignación) :

```
int main(void)
{
    Perro unPerro("Tim");
    cambiarNombre( unPerro );
    return 0;
}
void cambiarNombre(Perro& d) {
    d = Perro("Fifi"); // Sí modifica unPerro en main
                       // a través del operador de asignación
}
```

En el caso de los argumentos pasados por puntero en C++ tiene los mismos efectos que en Java, puesto que los punteros en C++ también se pasan por valor, igual que las referencias de Java :

```
int main(void)
{
    Perro* unPerro = new Perro("Tim");
    cambiarNombre( unPerro );
    return 0;
}
void cambiarNombre(Perro* d) {
    // Como en Java, no tiene efecto sobre la variable unPerro en main
    d = new Perro("Fifi");
}
```

Hasta aquí las referencias de Java se parecen mucho a los punteros en C++ y son muy distintas a las referencias en C++.
Pero también hay importantes diferencias entre los punteros en C++ y las referencias en Java :

- Recolección de basura. Los ejemplos de punteros C++ anteriores tendrían escapes de memoria (memory leaks), requieren de liberar la memoria con `delete` para que no se produzcan.
- Los punteros C++ tienen aritmética de punteros.
- Las referencias en Java están fuertemente tipadas.
- Las referencias en Java se implementan normalmente almacenando sus direcciones de memoria, igual que en los punteros, pero esto no es obligatorio en la especificación de Java y sería posible crear una máquina virtual en que las referencias estén asociadas a entradas de un diccionario en vez de a direcciones de memoria u otros mecanismos de indirección.

Comment: Creo que esto se resume en: Java pasa todo por valor **sin excepción**, mientras que en C++ tienes la libertad de pasar por valor y por referencia, en base a la forma que uses provees (o restringes) libertad a los clientes del API.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza en lo que a paso de parámetros se refiere sí, se resume en eso. Pero hay otras cuestiones en que las referencias de C++ y Java se diferencian. Como el poder declarar variables referencia sin inicialización explícita en Java y no poder en C++. O que el operador de asignación en Java con referencias haga algo completamente distinto a lo que hace el operador asignación con referencias en C++.

Answer (score 2):

Sin dar tantas vueltas, en Java todo se pasa por valor. La razón por la que **parece que los objetos se pasan por referencia** es porque en realidad, cuando pasas un objeto como parámetro, en realidad estás pasando el valor de la dirección en memoria a la que apunta, es por esto que puedes cambiar las propiedades del objeto por medio de su dirección, pero si intentas volver a instanciar, la dirección se perderá y se le asignará una nueva (del reciente instancamiento).

```
Gato gato = new Gato("Minino");
System.out.println(gato.getNombre()); // Minino
cambiarGato(gato);

public void cambiarGato(Gato gato) { // dirección de gato
    gato.setNombre("Michifu");
    gato = new Gato("Firulais"); // se reasigna una nueva dirección y se pierde la dirección original
}

System.out.println(gato.getNombre()); // Michifu
```

Comment: Pero hay diferencias que no tienen nada que ver con el paso de parámetros. Este código en Java `Gato gato1 = new Gato("1"); Gato gato2 = new Gato("2"); Gato gatoA = gato1; Gato gatoB = gato2; gatoA = gatoB; gatoA.asignaNombre("Fifi"); System.out.println( gatoB.obtenerNombre() );` y este en C++ `Gato* gato1 = new Gato("1");Gato* gato2 = new Gato("2"); Gato& gatoA = *gato1; Gato& gatoB = *gato2; gatoA = gatoB;gatoA.asignaNombre("Fifi");std::cout << gatoB.obtenerNombre()<< std::endl;` usan ambos referencias y tienen la misma estructura pero dan un resultado totalmente distinto.

Comment: Obviamente la diferencia entre ambos es que no tienen similitud en la forma en la que se usan punteros porque simplemente en Java no lo haces; los punteros se manejan implícitamente y no explícitamente como C++, Go, entre otros. No hay forma de comparar una característica de C++ con algo que en Java no existe pragmáticamente.

Comment: @Jose Antonio Dura Olmos, el problema es que en C++ las referencias no son equivalentes a las referencias en Java, sino que los más parecido en C++ a una referencia de Java es un puntero. Cuando haces Gato& gatoA = *gato1, obtienes lo que deseas. Pero cuando despues haces gatoA = gatoB, estás copiando el contenido de gatoB (gato2) en gatoA (gato1), con lo que no obtienes el resultado deseado. Si utilizas punteros para todos los casos, sí obtendrás el resultado que buscas.

Comment: A mi parecer, esto es pura semántica. Los que programan en Java suelen decir que en Java se pasa "el valor de la referencia". Los que programamos en C, llamamos a eso "punteros". La diferencia es que en C y C++ puedes incluso mandar un puntero al puntero, y con eso modificar el contenido. Y hablando de semántica, creo que es incorrecto decir que en Java se manda por "valor", porque no es el valor del objeto lo que se manda, sino el *valor de la referencia* como apuntaste (el valor hace referencia al contenido)