# No pasan los valores de un método a otro para mostrarlos

Tags: java

No llegan los datos de diferentes tipos recopilados en un método para pasar al otro método para mostrarlos. La idea es que **un método recopila datos, y otro método muestra los datos**. ¿O no es necesario pasarlos y son variables publicas que se trabajan desde cualquier método?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String valor1;
    Int valor2;
    double valor3;
    recopilarDatos(string valor1, int valor2, double valor3);
    mostrarDatos(string valor1, int valor2, double valor3);
}

/*Este método recopila datos*/
public static void recopilarDatos(string valor1, int valor2, double valor3){
    valor1 = "undostres";
    valor2 = 123;
    valor3 = 1,23;
}

/*Este método muestra los datos*/
public static void mostrarDatos(string valor1, int valor2, double valor3){
    System.out.println(valor1);
    System.out.println(valor2);
    System.out.println(valor3);
}
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿En Java los argumentos se pasan por valor o por referencia?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1402/en-java-los-argumentos-se-pasan-por-valor-o-por-referencia)

Answer (score 2):

Bueno en el caso específico que planteas no es necesario que recopiles los datos a no ser que estos sean globales.

Y bueno voy a mencionarte algunos errores que tienes y al final te pondre un ejemplo  de como podrias realizarlo:

Comenzare por el metodo `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String valor1;
    Int valor2; // Es int y no Int
    double valor3;

    // Cuando utilizas un método no debes escribir los tipos de cada uno sino simplemente los metodos
    recopilarDatos(string valor1, int valor2, double valor3);
    mostrarDatos(string valor1, int valor2, double valor3);
}
```

---

Metodos `recopilarDatos()` y `mostrarDatos()`

El error que veo en ambos es el uso de `string` en lugar de `String`, y también el uso de la coma `,` en lugar de punto `.` ya que pusiste `1,23` en lugar de `1.23`.

---

Pero bueno yo vengo de **JAVA 8** asi que probablemente se pueda realizar esto en posteriores versiones y si es asi corregirme porfavor.

Bien ahora te dejo un ejemplo de como pudiste haberlo realizado con variables globales:

```
static String valor1;
static int valor2;
static double valor3;
/*Este método recopila datos*/
public static void recopilarDatos(String v1, int v2, double v3){
    valor1 = v1;
    valor2 = v2;
    valor3 = v3;
}

/*Este método muestra los datos*/
public static void mostrarDatos(){
    System.out.println(valor1);
    System.out.println(valor2);
    System.out.println(valor3);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    recopilarDatos("valor", 1, 1.23);
    mostrarDatos();
}
```

Puesto que estas usando métodos estáticos no podrás hacer uso de `this` y por lo tanto el ejemplo que te pongo es sobre éste ambiente. Imagino que cuando desarrolles con `clases` separadas podrás utilizar variables privadas, etc.

Espero te sirva la información que te doy ;) Saludos

Comment: Sin mencionar que escribe string y es String. 
Pero, está muy bien explicado

Comment: Remarcar también que para asignar un valor a un tipo de dato **double** no se usa la ',' `1,23` sino que el '.' `1.23`.Por lo demás buena respuesta.

Comment: Ahhhh si eso también lo vi pero se me olvido ponerlo XD

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String valor1 = "undostres";
    int valor2 = 123;
    double valor3 = 123;
    recopilarDatos(valor1, valor2, valor3);//aquí no debes especificar el tipo de entrada de datos
    mostrarDatos(valor1, valor2, valor3);
}

/*Este método recopila datos*/
public static void recopilarDatos(String valor1, int valor2, double valor3){ }

/*Este método muestra los datos*/
public static void mostrarDatos(String valor1, int valor2, double valor3){
    System.out.println(valor1);
    System.out.println(valor2);
    System.out.println(valor3);
    }

}
```